# Saving form values, jquery.rte.js

Tags: jquery, rte

So i have a form that has many fields and i made a nice little js script that will serialize my form, send it to the sessions scripts, and save the form based on the form id.

`var values = $("#my-form").serialize() + "&formId=" + "my-form";
    $.post("mysweetscript.php", values);`

The issue is not with the script side of things saving.  The problem is with the getting all the form values.  I use the jquery plugin, [jquery.rte.js](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html), which hides my textarea and turns it to an iframe where i can do bolding and list procedures.  Sweet?  Yes, does $("#my-form").serialize() bring back the value of the input?  No.  It gives whatever value starts off in that textarea (probably because the rte just hides the textarea).  If i do this...

`$(function() {
        $.each($(".myinput"), function(key, value) {
             alert(key + " => " + value);
        });
    });`
This shows two different values.  First being a textarea, the second being an iframe.  I was wondering if there was a way i could get the value from the IFRAME.  I tried...
`$(function() {
        var inputs = $(".myrte");
        alert(inputs[1]);
        alert(inputs[1].html());
        alert($(inputs[1]).val());
        alert($(inputs[1]).html());
    });`

The error console on Moz-firefox shows this error.  `$(".myrte")[1].val is not a defined function`  even though `$(".myrte")[1]` will return object IFrame...

Any help?  I need to get the formatted text off there.  One weird note.  When i submit the form, the PHP side of things gets the formatted text... confusing? yes! :)  So i can save the values easy on submit, but not during edit.   Plus who likes losing all their typings when editing a form, not me!

Answer (score 0):

So the storing forms procedure now includes an `extraInfo` parameter that looks like.

`this.saveForm = function(extraInfo) {
var values = form.serialize();
values += "&formId=" + form.attr("id") + "&action=saveValues" + extraInfo;`

And the calling code looks like.

`processForm.saveForm("&mySweetRTETextArea=" + encodeURI($(".mySweetRTETextArea").contents().find("body").html()));`

I would love if someone could explain why!  When i execute the $.each, it brings 2 results back from $(.mySweetRTETextArea) because there is a textarea and the new iframe, but somehow calling contents() goes to the correct one... CONFUSED!! help?